# how to use a list of data as keyvalue pair

Tags: c#, list, dictionary

I have `nodeID_List` ; `nodeX_List`; `nodeY_List` ; `nodeZ_List`; these list,the first one is a list of integers and the other three are list of doubles. How can I create a dictionary where the key will be each int from the list and the 3 doubles will be the values for the key. I tried with tuples but I was not able to format it correctly.

```
Tuple<int, double, double, double> tuple_NodeData;
        nodeData_List = this.GetNodeInfo();
        nodeID_List = this.GetNodeIDInfo();
        nodeX_List = this.GetNodeXInfo();
        nodeY_List = this.GetNodeYInfo();
        nodeZ_List = this.GetNodeZInfo();

        for (int iNode = 0; iNode < nodeData_List.Count; iNode++)
        {
            tuple_NodeData = new Tuple<int, double, double, double>
                  (nodeID_List[iNode], nodeX_List[iNode], nodeY_List[iNode], nodeZ_List[iNode]);

        }
```

Comment: Your code should work (you might want to remove the key from the value). You just need to add it to a dictionary

Answer (score 0):

Will this do?

```
Dictionary<int, double[]> dict = new Dictionary<int, double[]>();

for (int i = 0; i <  nodeID_List.Count; i++) {
  dict.Add(nodeID_List[i], new double[] {nodeX_List[i], nodeY_List[i], nodeZ_List[i]});
}
```

However, I advise you to put the X, Y and Z into a new class:

```
public class Coordinate {
  public double X {get;set;}
  public double Y {get;set;}
  public double Z {get;set;}

  public Coordinate(double _x, double _y, double _z) {
    X = _x;
    Y = _y;
    Z = _z;
  }
}
```

And then do this instead:

```
Dictionary<int, Coordinate> dict = new Dictionary<int, Coordinate>();

for (int i = 0; i <  nodeID_List.Count; i++) {
  dict.Add(nodeID_List[i], new Coordinate(nodeX_List[i], nodeY_List[i], nodeZ_List[i]));
}
```

After that you van retrieve data from this dictionary using the key, which will get you a coordinate:

```
Coordinate coor = dict[5]; // Select coordinate with ID = 5
```

After that you can get the coordinates using:

```
int x = coor.X;
int y = coor.Y;
int z = coor.Z;
```

Comment: can you please also show me how I must retrieve data from this dictionary ,this may be very easy but I am unable to do.thanks in advance

Comment: Inconsistent accessibility: return type 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<int,TestProject.NodeInfo.Coordinate>' is less accessible than method 'TestProject.NodeInfo.GetNodeID_AlongWithCoordinates()'

Comment: Dictionary<int, Coordinate> dict = new Dictionary<int, Coordinate>();

        public Dictionary<int, Coordinate> GetNodeID_AlongWithCoordinates()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < nodeID_List.Count; i++)
            {
                dict.Add(nodeID_List[i], new Coordinate(nodeX_List[i], nodeY_List[i], nodeZ_List[i]));
            }
            return dict;
        }

Comment: wrote like above and getting above error,please help

Comment: I forgot some 'public's, my apologies. Please see my updated answer.

Comment: if I want to take coordinate as a struct instead of class, is it possible and How should i write the code

Comment: Yes, that would be possible. Simply replace 'class' with 'struct' and I think that should work.

Comment: D.G. is your question answered? Can you please accept one of the answers?

Answer (score 0):

Your dictionary would be of type `IDictionary<int, Tuple<double, double, double>>`. The rest of your code is almost right, you just need to add the tuple to the dictionary.

```
    var dict = new Dictionary<int, Tuple<double, double, double>>();
    nodeData_List = this.GetNodeInfo();
    nodeID_List = this.GetNodeIDInfo();
    nodeX_List = this.GetNodeXInfo();
    nodeY_List = this.GetNodeYInfo();
    nodeZ_List = this.GetNodeZInfo();

    for (int iNode = 0; iNode < nodeData_List.Count; iNode++)
    {
      dict.add(
        nodeID_List[iNode],
        new Tuple<double, double, double>(nodeX_List[iNode], nodeY_List[iNode], nodeZ_List[iNode]));
    }
```

Comment: please help me by showing that how must I retrieve data i.e x,y,z coordinates based on the id from the above code.I am sorry if am I asking silly questions. thanks in advance.please reply me asap

Comment: Just like you access any other dictionary (please read up on the basics of .NET and dictionaries, you will find great resources on MSDN): `dict[your_node_id].Item3`.